# Website Here, Linking to Database There on other Server?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to link to a MySql database that is on another server and hosted somewhere else entirely?

Comment: You'll have to clarify. Define "link"

Comment: You've mentioned in a comment that you're moving a Joomla based site.  I strongly recommend you migrate the database along with the site.  Joomla is slow as it is - if your database is not on the same server as the site, you may experience a really slow site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, just change the host configuration on your connection string

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: Great! I have to upgrade Joomla and wanted to do it on another server :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect to a remote server.

[How to Enable Remote Access To MySQL Database Server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: You might edit/reword your answer, as at first glance it appears to be instructions on how to administer a remote database

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Check out connection strings http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Answer (score 1):

I have to recommend against it if you have a lot a data to transfer via the web, but within the network of company it works. In fact, in a common solution : you put the data on a dedicated server with performance/redundancy capabilites.

When you can connect to a local database you use a connection string such as 127.0.0.1:3306/somthing_something. With that in mind, you realise you can easily change this to another host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as a path is provided to you to get "at" the MySql server. In other words, the person hosting the SQL server would have to ensure that a port is open on their firewall so that your application could talk to it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, however, performance (bandwidth, latency) may be an issue depending on your specific requirements

Comment: Agreed. With a connection string example this answer would merit an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.  The most common production deployment has the database hosted on a seperate server.  What might be interesting to you is the [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) that you application defines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it is not wise solution, since your users will experience additional lags when your application will be connecting to some distant database.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the hosted MySql server has a public IP you can access.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying this for days with a joomla site and can't get it to connect to a remote DB. The db is configured to be accessible from all hosts but given  that joomla has a config file that specifies seperately the host, DB name, username and pass (you can't create a connection string manually) I'm not sure what other options I have to get this to work.

Did the orginal poster have success with this?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely - and that is how my web host implements MySQL databases: As soon you create one it is created in a cluster of servers. Along with username&password pairs, and database name, they give you the server name.

Similarly, you can do it on your own LAN, or even over the Internet. I've done it over a LAN for testing. I would not recommend doing it over the Internet though due to very slow speed and an increase in security risk.